# Laravel Livewire Select2 issue with new app

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have standard TALL Stack new APP
& I am trying to make select2 from Laravel 8 & Livewire 2

I have follow this
in my live-wire blade I have added this

```
<div class="w-1/3 px-3 mb-5" wire:ignore>
                <x-jet-label for="uid" value="{{ __('Users') }}" />
                <select class="select2 w-full rounded-md border border-gray-200 p-2 focus:outline-none focus:border-gray-500" id="uid" wire:model.defer="uid">
                <option value="" selected>Choose User</option>
                @if(isset($users))
                @foreach($users as $user)
                    <option value="{{ $user->id }}">{{ $user->name }}</option>
                @endforeach
                @endif
            </select>                
                <x-jet-input-error for="uid" class="mt-2" />
            </div>
```

at the bottom of this page

```
@push('scripts')
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.select2').select2();
    });
</script>
@endpush
```

Its not loading Select2 but there is no error in console.
Also I have added

```
@livewireStyles
@livewireScripts
```

in layout blade also.

Do I need to add any extra CSS or JS or what I am doing wrong.

Even I have added this in my blade but still not working

@section('style')

@endsection

@section('scripts')

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
       

        $('#FirstOption').select2({
            placeholder: 'Select an option',
        });


    });

</script>
```

@endsection

Thanks

Comment: Have you loaded the Select2 library onto the page? Do you stack your scripts somewhere in the layout? Since you're using jQuery, is that loaded as it should?

Comment: Thanks but I did't load Select2 library or jquery, do I need to load them also?

Comment: Place the select2 script outside the `document ready` function